# Grails, comparing two objects?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a Client object.

```
class Client{
String firstName
String lastName
String middleName
}
```

Then I have a form where mother cannot be equal to father. Which validator would be more proper for comparing the clients? Is there even a difference? I've tried both and they work, though I'm not too sure if it may just be a coincidence. I could be wrong too. How is comparing done for two objects? Any advice?

`val.id == obj.father.id` or `val == obj.father`

```
class Form{
Client mother
Client father

static constraints = {
mother (nullable:true, validator: { val, obj ->
            if(mother equals father){
                return ["invalid.motherCannotBeEqualFather.label"]  
            }
        })
}
}
```

Comment: I think that this article can help you solve your doubts [hibernate Equals and HashCode](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode)

Answer (score 2):

`val == obj.father`

Will result in `val.equals(obj.father)`, as Groovy overloads ==. The default behavior of this is to simply check for reference equality, which can be dangerous. Hibernate will attempt to ensure equality (see the link by Fabiano), but it can be unreliable.

`val.id == obj.father.id`

Will ensure that the two objects represent different entries in the database table associated with your domain object. When you save a new domain object, Grails assigns the object an id that is unique within its domain. By default this is accomplished with an incremented id in the DB table representing your object.

If mother and father have already been saved to the DB when this validation is performed, it could be a useful equality check.

If you simply trying to prevent firstName, lastName, and middleName from being the same on a form, which it kind of seems like, this validation will only be effective if you've defined uniqueness constraints on those fields as a group in the client domain, e.g. `firstName(unique: ['lastName', 'middleName'])`.

Consider just defining a validator that explicitly ensures the uniqueness you're looking for.

Comment: My aim is that the mother and father should not be the same object. I don't want to be too tight on the names since there is a possibility that a couple could share the same name (A rare case but hey it happens http://today.msnbc.msn.com/id/31994977/ns/today-relationships/t/kelly-hildebrandt-wed-kelly-hildebrandt/#.UKjwjrQgd5M).

Comment: In short, `val.id == obj.father.id` and `val == obj.father` are the same as long as mother and father were retrieved in the same hibernate session (I'm pretty sure). Regardless of that, `val.id == obj.father.id` will always effectively distinguish between persisted domain objects. I would just use `.id`, as it seems to be what you're looking for. One note: be sure the objects have been persisted (saved) when you perform your validation, otherwise the id property will be null for both and you will end up with `null == null //true`

Comment: yes.. The mother and father have to be present before hand, before the file is made. Their names will appear in a dropdown menu, so if it's not there, they'll have to be created first. My only worry is let's say, we have 2 people in the database, A(id:1) & B(id:2), I created a form successfully. If for instance, B(id:2) is deleted, and I add a new client C, what would his id be? Is it 2? Or would it increment to 3?

Comment: It kind of depends, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675169/how-does-hibernate-generator-increment-handle-deletes. In short, id will be 3 unless you restart the DB. Regardless, it is a moot point for your purposes. The id value is guaranteed to be unique among persisted objects, and thus a valid way to test for equality.