# Find if two objects match

Tags: groovy, properties, iteration

I have a method to match two objects. A match will happen if each of the first object's properties matches the second one's. I know in Groovy I can iterate over the fields of one object to do this. The problem is that I am getting an exception that I can't figure out.

In code:

Method: `private match(Project projectToMatch, Project project)`

Project class:

```
class Project 
{
    final String name
    final Person techLead
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
private boolean match(Project projectManaged, Project project) {
    project.properties.each { prop, value ->
        if(value != projectManaged["$prop"] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

But I am getting:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Closure  com.gustavo.tribal.ProjectManagerImplTest$_testEditProjectShouldNotEditIfPriorityAlreadyExists_closure3@32da5a84 
should have failed with an exception of type com.gustavo.tribal.exceptions.WrongProjectException, 
instead got Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object
```

Both parameters are not null, but the values of techLead is for both. I am sure there is a relation between the null value and the exception, but I can't get it right.

*EDIT*:

The test is:

```
void testEditProjectShouldNotEditIfPriorityAlreadyExists() {
    projectManagerImpl.addProject(project)
    projectManagerImpl.addProject(project2)
    def msg = shouldFail(WrongProjectException) {
        projectManagerImpl.editProject(project, project2b)
    }
    assertEquals "Can't edit project as the requested priority (" + project2b.priority + ") is already in use", msg
}
```

And the code for `editProject`:

```
void editProject(Project project, Project editedProject) {
    for(Project projectManaged : allProjects) {
        if(match(projectManaged, project)) {
            if(projectManaged.priority != editedProject.priority && usedPriorities.get(editedProject.priority)) {
                throw new WrongProjectException("Can't edit project as the requested priority (" + editedProject.priority + ") is already in use")
            }
            removeProject(project)
            addProject(editedProject)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got a *unit test* that's failing.  Could you show us that code?

Comment: Not sure why you're not using `equals` and `hashcode`?

Comment: As far as I have seen reading the literature (i.e. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393964/grails-comparing-two-objects)), I have seen that `==` is pretty much the same as `equals` (I am quite new to Groovy). On the other hand, most of the parameters can be null, so I should not do `x.equals(y)`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was missing a parenthesis in my `match` method. Also, instead of `projectManaged["$prop"]` I should have used `projectManaged[prop]`